# How can I delete from an array

Tags: javascript

i know there are similar threads but i have tried what you suggested there but still couldn´t solve my problem.

```
for(var i = text.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if(text.charCodeAt(i) < 42 || text.charCodeAt(i) > 57)
        {
            text.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    alert(text);
```

Why is alert(text); not executed? Something is wrong with the Splice, please help me.

Comment: @AbdennourToumi Java != JavaScript

Comment: @AbdennourToumi possible confusion of lanaguage.. Java != JavaScript

Comment: oh . yes .... you are right

Comment: make a JSFIDDLE.NET and look in the console

Comment: You're working with a string. There is no `splice` method for strings.

Comment: [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) or [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)? Since we do not see what `text` is in your question. `charCodeAt` implies it's a string but in your question's title you are asking for an Array.

Comment: `text = text.replace(/[^*+,-./0-9]/g, "");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the string in javascript doesn't have a splice method. You need to convert it in an array.

```
text = text.split('');
text.splice(i,1);
text = text.join('');
```

And, as an array, you can't use the method charAt but

```
if(text[i] < 42 || text[i] > 57)
```

Talking about what's the best way to achieve this task, I would rather suggest to have a look at different solutions way better than this, performance wise.

Here you can find a benchmark where you can see how using the string method *slice* is way more performant.

http://jsperf.com/split-or-slice-for-string-splice/2

Comment: Converting it to an array works, but sounds like overkill. How about `function splice(string, index, howMany) { return string.substring(0, index) + string.substring(index + howMany);}`

Comment: yes I could be another solution. I just answered his question wondering why the alert wasn't been executed. That was because of the javascript error in the for loop. Going forward, it's plenty of different solutions to solve this particular task. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the .slice() method.

```
text.slice(i,1);
```

Answer (score -4):

The alert is not executed because you did not declare it in the beginning of your script.

```
var text = [];

for(var i = text.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if(text.charCodeAt(i) < 42 || text.charCodeAt(i) > 57)
        {
            text.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    alert(text);
```

Comment: text is obviously a string and not an empty array